# turning a non-template class into a template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a self made data structure (for example linked list) that works well, but when I made the class I did it based around strings, but now I want to take that data structure, and use it to hold another self made data type. I know that this involves templates (the ability to take a working data structure and apply any data type to it), but I have not really worked with them.

what steps should I follow to turn a non-template class into a template class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you need to do is put the template specification in front:

```
template <class T>
class A {
  ...
};
```

Then use T instead of using your string type.

There are lots of other things to consider when creating templates, but it depends on the particular situation.

You will specify your new type when you use the template:

```
A<MyType> my_object;
```

Comment: then the question that directly follows is how do I specify that I am using the new type, and do I need to include the file that holds the type that I am using in side the now template class

Comment: I added some detail to my answer.  Your type doesn't need to be declared when the template class is declared, because the template class doesn't know anything about what type T will be.  When you instantiate the class the type will need to have been declared.

Comment: thanks. the reason for using making this a template is so I can hold unique data types, and not have to rewrite the structure every time I want to use it (I think this is one of the arguments for templates, not sure). not to mention that it will do amazingly well for the present application by making it usable with the new type

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "unique".  You want to use templates if the alternative (without templates) would be to create several very similar classes.

Comment: so are you saying that I shouldn't be using a template if I am using one data type, and only use them for multiple types in the same program. from what I understood it was for re-usability throughout usefulness independent of program, and number of uses within any program.

Comment: If your template is only going to be used with one type, there isn't much point in making it be a template.  It is like making a function with a parameter that will always be passed the same value.

Comment: thank you for the info, and the frame of reference. maybe I was doing with templates what they say never to do with design patterns fit the pattern to the problem instead of the problem to the pattern. I'll give this some thought thanks for the help anyways it was still insightful

Answer (score 2):

that is basic actions

1. Move all method definitions of your class from .cpp to .h file
2. Put template specifications (`template <class T>`) before all declarations and definitions
3. Change all class name specifiers to template names, i.e. `A::A(){}` should became `A<T>::A(){}`
4. If it required, change the names of method calls to ones with type parameters
5. Change all entries of the previous type to the type parameter name

can be a lot of the other things of course.

Comment: I think that this can be done independently of separating stubs, and implementations (just did it). so step1 is actually irrelevant (more perfect world kind of thing), and step2 is dependent on step1, but 3-5 are still relevant in all regards. you might want to check the wording of step 4.